# Предлог "за" и падежи

Tags: предлоги, падежи

В каком случае предлог "за" употребляется с винительным падежем, а в каком с творительным?

Answer (score 1):

Падежи в русском языке многозначны, но при этом для каждого падежа можно определить ЦЕНТРАЛЬНОЕ значение.

Для В.п. это НАПРАВЛЕННОСТЬ действия на объект, для ненаправленного Т.п это орудийная семантика, то есть всё то, что способствует осуществлению действия и придает ему определенный вид, характер, образ.

Предлог ЗА может участвовать в управлении как В.п., так и Т.п., сравнить: забежать (куда?) за дом - играть (где?)  за домом. В первом случае объект в В.п. указывает НАПРАВЛЕНИЕ действия, во втором объект в Т.п. определяет пространство, где происходит действие.

Answer (score 0):

*Я болею за "Зенит"* - винительный.
*Он пошел за грибами* - творительный.